# How update a transformation done on a read file?

Tags: refactoring, transformation, rascal

How update the content of a file, "teste.java" as example with the result of a transformation?

```
loc s =  |project://java-sample/teste.java|;
content = readFile(s);
CompilationUnit cUnit = parse(#CompilationUnit, content);
visit(cUnit) {
   case (Statement) `if (<Expression cond>) { return true; } else { return false; }` =>  
        (Statement) `return <Expression cond>;`
}
```

Comment: You can also pass the source location as an argument to the parse function directly. Gives for better trees with offsets and locations pointing to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `visit` returns the new tree. You can save that tree to a file using `writeFile` that will unparse it and save the file:

```
loc s =  |project://java-sample/teste.java|;
content = readFile(s);
CompilationUnit cUnit = parse(#CompilationUnit, content);
cUnitNew = visit(cUnit) { // note the assignment!
   case (Statement) `if (<Expression cond>) { return true; } else { return false; }` =>  
        (Statement) `return <Expression cond>;`
}
writeFile(s, cUnitNew); // write the new string to disk
```